# How to update the last element in a string?

Tags: python

I am trying to  increment the last element in the below strings by 1,expected output shows what is needed,my current code below works for all cases but for  `version3` and `version4` cases,how do I fix this?

```
version1 =  '1151.1'
version2 =  '4.1.1'
version3 = '275.1.2.99'
version4 = '369'

version = version3[:-1] + str(int(version3[-1]) + 1)
print(version)
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
1151.2
4.1.2
275.1.2.100
370
```

Comment: Is there a standard library function that could split a period-separated string into a list?

Comment: @DavidMaze: Or perhaps a standard method of the string class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the "element" you're talking about is actually the last segment of the string, delimited by a period (`.`). One way to perform the intended task is to first split the string by `.`'s, and then increment and re-concatenate from there.

```
version1 = '1151.1'
version2 = '4.1.1'
version3 = '275.1.2.99'
version4 = '369'

def increment_last_element(version):
    return '.'.join(version.split('.')[:-1] + [str(int(version.split('.')[-1]) + 1)])

print(increment_last_element(version1))
# Output: 1151.2
```

Here's the breakdown:

```
# Join the spliced str back together with periods
'.'.join(  
    # Split the str by periods; retain all previous values
    version.split('.')[:-1] +
    # Convert to str
    # (also have to convert the str into a list for list concatenation)
    [str(  
    # Increment last element in the spliced string by 1
     int(version.split('.')[-1]) + 1)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a simple iteration with `str.split` and `str.join`

**Ex:**

```
l = ['1151.1', '4.1.1', '275.1.2.99', '369']
for i in l:
    val = i.split(".")
    val[-1] = str(int(val[-1])+1)
    print(".".join(val))
```

**Output:**

```
1151.2
4.1.2
275.1.2.100
370
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `version3` is a string so `version[-1]` will return only the last character of the string.

You should convert your version string into an array of integers, increase the last one by one, then convert back into strings.

```
version_array = [int(x) for x in version3.split('.')]
version_array[-1] += 1
print(".".join([str(x) for x in version_array]))
```